# assign value to struct member

Tags: c, pointers, struct, embedded

Wwhy cant I not assign value [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNeQS.png)

`A1->a |= 5;`

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} A;

int main(){
    A *A1 = (A *) 0x100; //this is for example, an address of a register

    printf("A1.a is at %p\n", &(A1->a));
    printf("A1.b is at %p\n", &(A1->b));
    printf("A1.c is at %p\n", &(A1->c));

    A1->a |= 5; //this line doesnt work
    printf("A1.a = %d ", A1->a);
    return 0;
}
```

`A1->a |= 5;` this line doesnt work, cant any body help me understand why ?
I am trying to learn embedded programing and its programming style.

Comment: You can't just dereference a random memory address like `0x100`.

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: Code says it is a register address.

Comment: Your code is running on Windows and there is no register at the address 0x100. You cannot simply read an arbitrary memory address.

Comment: i am following an embedded course for stm32f4 , but since i dont have money yet to by the stm32f4 board, so right now i am just trying to replicate simple example code in DevCpp program to see how it works. So this mean i have to work with the actual board to see real real result ? thanks you for your replies, and sorry in advance if i dont express clearly because english not my first language

Comment: 0x100 must be a valid read/write address on the target. It isn't neither on STM32 nor on your PC.

Comment: @Jabberwocky @ Lundin I want to clarify that : i know 0X100 is not an actual address, i was just trying to put a random address to see how the code work because i am learning the codeing style of embedded. thank you for your reply . base on the replies i see that i have to use an valid address that allow me to read it, is that correct ?

Comment: @phạmhữuTrí see my answer

Comment: @Hitokiri i am following an embedded course and in this course they use different syntax of coding, they dont use malloc, they typecast the struct into a pointer and point it to an address of a register to configre its bit field. like so :                                                               #define __vo volatile

typedef struct
{
 __vo uint32_t MODER;
 __vo uint32_t OTYPER;
    __vo uint32_t OSPEEDR;
}GPIO_RegDef_t;

GPIO_RegDef_t* pGPIOA = (GPIO_RegDef_t*)0x40020000;

Comment: @phạmhữuTrí `A *A1 = &A0;` it means you make the pointer point to the address of `A0`. In the course, you can do `GPIO_RegDef_t* pGPIOA = (GPIO_RegDef_t*)0x40020000`, because, the user knows beforehand the address of register. In your code you can print the address of `A0` , then cast `A1 = (A *) the_address of `A0`

Comment: @Hitokiri thank you , i understand

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you , i understand

Comment: @phạmhữuTrí you are welcome :))

Comment: @phạmhữuTrí That code is from ST's bloatware register map. It will work fine on STM32 with their specific tool chain. From a general embedded C perspective, stuff like `(GPIO_RegDef_t*)0x40020000` is very questionable. Not so much because it's accessing a physical address, but because of the wild cast to a structure type. Normal embedded systems declare an instance of the struct and then map that struct to the register map, in some linker-dependent way.

Answer (score 0):

```
A *A1 = (A *) 0x100;
```

Your problem is this line. You cannot reference to an address that you do not own it. You do not know in this address, you can read or write the data.

you can reference to an address of a variable:

```
A A0;
A *A1 = &A0;
```

Comment: The code says that `0x100` is the address of a register.

Comment: This is tagged embedded, so using malloc is not the correct answer. There's no undefined behavior either, the PC simply doesn't allow direct access to that address.

Comment: So for example, the well-defined but implementation-specific behavior on POSIX-flavoured OS would be to raise a SIGSEGV signal, and the well-defined behavior on Windows is to return 0xC0000005 from the process - access violation.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is supposed to run on machine with Memory Management Unit active, then you will end up with a segmentation fault because the address you're trying to access is not mapped to your process.Keep in mind, you cannot access memory beyond the memory space you've been allocated (unless you request it, malloc, mmap, etc).

If it is supposed to run on a machine without MMU active (on MCU) then you can freely access any memory address (unless you do not have any Memory Unit Protection active for that region). Basically you're trying to access three registers (0x100, 0x104, 0x108, suppose you run on 32 bit machine). Please take into account that "int" is a signed number, what happens if your register has bit 31 set to "1" ? The result will be interpreted as signed. Now try to use bitwise operation on signed numbers !!!! (certainly not the result you're expecting) .

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
   uint32_t a;
   uint32_t b;
   uint32_t c;
} A;

volatile A *A1 = (volatile A*)0x100;
```

Just to make sure, do you really want to use bitwise ?

```
A1->a | = 5 ; // if a = 1 => a = 7
```

If you're expecting to set the 5th bit, then you need to do:

```
A1->a |= (1 << 5); // if a = 1 => a = 33
```